# How to cast String to Key in java

Tags: java, cryptography

I want to cast an string to key type.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(publicKeyFile));
String publicKey = br.readLine();//(Key) keyIn.readObject();
br.close();

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, publicKey);
```

`cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, publicKey);` needs `publickey` of a type with the interface [`Key`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Key.html).

So how do I cast string to key?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292389/converting-key-to-string-and-back-to-key-java

Comment: I don't know, but "cast" is not the right verb to use here.  "Parse" probably is more like it.

Comment: I found this answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8029555/16959

Comment: This looks like the Java Class you are after: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAPublicKey.html though instantiating one is a little trickier (and fully outlined in the answer I linked to)

Comment: Depends on the key format in the key file, probably either PEM or XML. Please show the contents of the file. There is no such thing as a universal encoding of public keys, they can be encoded in different ways.

Comment: What is the content of the `publicKeyFile` file? If it is PEM encoding of the public key, then JCA has no means to read keys in that format. If it is DER encoding of the public key, then read it as `byte[]`, use the `byte[]` the create `X509EncodedKeySpec`, use `KeyFactory` to convert that key spec into a key.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [KeyFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/security/KeyFactory.html) to create the Key you need based on KeySpec.

Comment: True of course, but it may be tricky to find a key factory that supports a given text (file). Most of the time you will need some kind of parsing or conversion to binary as well, such as the Bouncy Castle PEM reader. Actually, since we still don't know the format, I'm voting to close the question.